# How to auto complete and suggest code in Visual Studio for C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have seen Visual Studio suggest code and auto complete code but I have search the web and the settings but cant find it.

for example writing Ob suggests Object obj = new Object();

Also is there a setting to auto place semicolon at the end of the line?

Comment: That feature is enabled by default. Are you saying you're never getting any suggestions?

Comment: there are some general settings under VS-options--> Text Editor --> C#-->Intellisense. But what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I am looking for code suggestion (not sure how exactly its called) for example writing Ob suggests Object obj = new Object(); Yes, I installed Visual Studio 2022 in 2 pc and never got those.

Comment: Are you working with a valid project?

Comment: Not sure what you mean valid project. I write simple Console apps (.Net Framework).